# Is VAE the same as the E-step of the EM algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, variational-autoencoder, evidence-lower-bound, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

#### EM(Expectation Maximum)

Target: maximize $p_\theta(x)$

$  p_\theta(x)=\frac{p_\theta(x, z)}{p_\theta(z \mid x)} \\\\$

Take log on both sides:

$ \log p_\theta(x)=\log p_\theta(x, z)-\log p_\theta(z \mid x) \\\\$

Introduce distribution  $q_\phi(z)$:

$ \log p_\theta(x)=\log \frac{p_\theta(x, z)}{q_\phi(z)}-\log \frac{p_\theta(z \mid x)}{q_\phi(x)} \\
\int_z q_\phi(x) \log p_\theta(x) d z=\int_z q_\phi(z) \log \frac{p_\theta(x, z}{q_\phi(z)} d z-\int_z q_\phi(z) \log \frac{p_\theta(z \mid x)}{q_\phi(x)} d z \\
 \log p_\theta(x)=\underbrace{\int q_\phi(z) \log \frac{p_\theta(x, z)}{q_\phi(z)} d z}_{E L B O}+\underbrace{\int_z q_\phi(z) \log \frac{q_\phi(z)}{p_\theta(z \mid x)} d z}_{K L\left(q_\phi(z) \| p_\theta(z \mid x)\right)} \\ $

Our target is to maximize $log\ p_{\theta}(x)$, and the idea of EM is to let KL=0  $ \Rightarrow $ $log\ p_{\theta}(x)=ELBO$, and then maximize  $log\ p_{\theta}(x)$  by maximizing ELBO.

- Do an algebraic variation on ELBO:

​      $ELBO=\int q_\phi(z) \log \frac{p_\theta(x, z)}{q_\phi(z)} d z=\int q_\phi(z) \log p_\theta(x, z)d z-\int q_\phi(z) \log {q_\phi(z)} d z$

${q_\phi(z)}$ is calculated in **E-step** (${q_\phi(z)}=p_{\theta^{(t)}}(z|x)$) , so when we are maximizing $ELBO$, we can treat$ \int q_\phi(z) \log {q_\phi(z)} d z$ as a constant.

So in order to maximize $ELBO$, we just need to maximize $\int q_\phi(z) \log p_\theta(x, z)d z=E_{q_\phi(z)}[\log p_\theta(x, z)]$

#### VAE(Variational autoEncoder)

The above EM algorithm has a important premise that $p_{\theta^{(t)}}(z|x)$ is tractable, so we can just make ${q_\phi(z)}=p_{\theta^{(t)}}(z|x)$ to make $KL$ = 0. But if  $p_{\theta^{(t)}}(z|x)$  is intractable, we have to use **Variational Inference** to make ${q_\phi(z)}$ approximate $p_{\theta^{(t)}}(z|x)$.

VAE minimizes ${K L\left(q_\phi(z) \| p_\theta(z \mid x)\right)} $ by maximizing $ELBO$. Do an algebraic variation on ELBO:

$-ELBO=\int q_\phi(z) \log p_\theta(z|x)d z+\underbrace{\int q_\phi(z) \log \frac{q_\phi(z)}{p_\theta(z)} d z}_{K L\left(q_\phi(z) \| p_\theta(z)\right)}$

Then we can use the gradient descent method for optimization.

**My question is:** The target of VAE is to maximise $ELBO$ and thus minimise ${K L\left(q_\phi(z) \| p_\theta(z \mid x)\right)} $, which is the same as the E-step of the EM algorithm. However, the sum of ELBO and KL remains the same, and it can not to increase $ logp(x).$ So VAE is just the E-step in the EM algorithm? How does it manage to fit the distribution of $x$ (increase $ logp(x)$)?